# My app on Playstore is giving me issues while the one I install using AS or APK works fine

Tags: android, static, google-play, mqtt

I am facing this weird problem. My app works fine when I install it from Android Studio, or using a direct APK file. But when I download the same version of app from Playstore I face issues. Issues I face on Playstore version:

I am using MQTT conncetion in it, that apparently disconnects randomly. Sometimes an MQTT call goes through fine and other times same call fails. It could be that Android is garbage collecting my static variables too soon.

One more thing  I want to highlight is that my app has some Flavor specific code and libraries. Not sure if that helps in identifying the problem.

Does an app installed from Playstore have different optimizations or something?

This is very strange issue for me.

Comment: If you install the release version it is the same. Optionally you can select that Android studio generates the APK from an App Bundle just to be safe.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Thanks. I used signingConfigs to run signed apk in my device and I can debug it on the go. Now how can I install APK using App bundle, that I can debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used signingConfigs in `build.gradle` to run my release APK on my device and I was able to reproduce the issue. Then I added Logs to catch the issue. It was an issue a quickJs library that I was using. I replaced it and it worked.